# my discord bot dosen't give role automaticly

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to make a discord bot that give a role to a user according to his league of legend rank that I get by scraping a website that give information. I create different role on my server. Example if he is bronze the bot gonna put the user in the bronze role. the user need to put `$rank 'username'` and this work fine but it's just dosen't give the role I dont have any error. the code is in french but the part where it dosent work is in english. The probleme is in line 57-60 (the end of the code):

```
import discord
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']


def startbot():
  global rank
  client = discord.Client()

  @client.event
  async def on_ready():
      print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author.id
    if message.content.startswith('$rank'):
      stringsplit = message.content.split()
      nmb = len(stringsplit)
      if nmb == 1:
        await message.channel.send("aucun username détecté. Ecrire ($rank USERNAME)")
        return
      else:
        headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36 OPR/82.0.4227.58',
        'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        }
        username = stringsplit[1]
        name = "https://na.op.gg/summoner/userName=" + username
        source = requests.get(name, headers = headers)
        try:
          soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")
        except:
          await message.channel.send("cette utilisateur n'existe pas.")
          return
        rank = soup.find('div' , class_="TierRank")
        try:
          rank = rank.text
        except:
          await message.channel.send("cette utilisateur n'existe pas.")
          return
        if rank == "Unranked":
          await message.channel.send("cette utilisateur est non classé.")
          return
        rank = rank.split()
        rank = rank[0]
  
    else:
      if message.author == client.user:
        return
      await message.delete()
      return
    

    @client.event
    async def on_message(member):
      role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name=rank)
      await client.add_roles(member, role)
  client.run(my_secret)

startbot()
```

Comment: There should only be one on_message why is there 2

Comment: I have no real experience in coding so im doing this for fun

Answer (score 0):

For prefixed commands you should be using `commands.Bot` not `discord.Client`.

Prefixed Commands should be defined as such:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=“=“)

@client.command()
async def cmd_name(ctx,*args):
    …
```

Comment: does this whould solve my probleme?

Comment: what's ur discord

Comment: its just a server that I creat so me and my friend can play